# weblogic.application.ModuleException in WLS Version: 12.1.2.0.0

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, deployment, weblogic12c

I have a Spring MVC application deployed in a WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.2.0.0.
but when I deploy to WL i have this problem:

```
       weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 68; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'security:global-method-security'.:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The mat
ching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'security:global-method-security'.
```

Here my applicationContext.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">


        <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

        <security:http auto-config="true">
            <security:csrf/>    
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"    />
        </security:http>

        <security:authentication-manager/>
```

and my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should add `spring-security-config` dependency.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```